# Activity name cast as parameter

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activitys and a class 'functions'. Some functions from my class are used in  all my activitIes.

Lets say that all my activities have some local variabiles. Same names same use in  all activities

I make a function în my class and in all my activities i call that function.

When i need to use a variabile i do (in my function) :

(Activityname).context.variabile(bla-bla)

How can i send Activityname as a parameter and use directly în The statement above?

Right now i use a string parameter and set namualy Activityname using 'if'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get a class's name by a method in the `Class` class :)

`MainActivity.class.getSimpleName` will return a `String` representation of MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Using a interface would be a better solution. Take a look at my pseudocode

```
//class with the used values
public class ReturnObject{
    int yourValue1;
    string yourValue2;

    //getters and setter
}

//simple interface which retuns the values
public interface IReturner{
    public ReturnObject returnObject();
}

//your activities
public class MyActivity1,2 and 3 extends Activity implements IRetuner{//implement the interface
    //other methods and stuff

    //override the interface its method to the actvities behaviour
    public override ReturnObject returnObject(){
        ReturnObject ro = new ReturnObject();
        //set values;
        return ro;
    }
}

//your functions class
public class functions{

    //some funcion used by the activity
    public void methodUsedByActivity(IReturner returner){
        ReturnObject ro = returner.returnObject();
        //Do stuff with the returnObject its values;  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use instanceof it will be much easier instead of passing activity name as string as below

```
if(((Activity)context) instanceof Activity1)
   //add related code here
if(((Activity)context) instanceof Activity2)
   //add related code here
```